ASP.NET Core use wrong static html file content with vite build
I'm using ASP.Net core SPA with svelte kit static-adapter, when publish project, the wwwroot folder get generate by vite build command for app.UseDefaultFiles(); app.UseStaticFiles();. Start the application and connect to top level urls like /[url], every things work fine, but when i access other url in sub directories like /[0]/[1], then error about import path happened (expect '../' instead of './')
Error in Sub Directory File
But in wwwroot the content is correct
<link href="../_app/immutable/assets/0.BWQ_AXWl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="../_app/immutable/entry/start.DSATCu1-.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="../_app/immutable/chunks/entry.CbekV8Il.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="../_app/immutable/chunks/scheduler.DKwKPiiE.js">

Promise.all([
    import("../_app/immutable/entry/start.DSATCu1-.js"),
    import("../_app/immutable/entry/app.Beql58MK.js")
]).then(([kit, app]) => {...});

As I test, the content of wwwroot folder changed won't affect what asp.net core response
There is my esproj of svetle project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.271090-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupCommand>npm run dev</StartupCommand>
    <BuildCommand>npm run build:staging_dev</BuildCommand>
    <JavaScriptTestRoot>src\</JavaScriptTestRoot>
    <JavaScriptTestFramework>Jest</JavaScriptTestFramework>
    <ShouldRunBuildScript>false</ShouldRunBuildScript>
    <BuildOutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\build</BuildOutputFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

And SPA properties group of host project:
 <PropertyGroup>
   <SpaRoot>..\..\src\Project.Client</SpaRoot>
   <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm run dev</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
   <SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:5173</SpaProxyServerUrl>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\Project.Client\Project.Client.esproj" >
     <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
   </ProjectReference>
 </ItemGroup>

How can i resolve this error? Or can someone explain me the behaviour of wwwroot folder in published application

using "~/" should get you to the special "wwwroot" folder.  Your routed paths are handled by core's executable.  Which is nowhere in particular as far as paths go... (though the executable file is located in the parent directory of wwwroot when deployed)  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0#serve-files-in-web-root
